# Why does my minecraft location_check predicate not run?

Tags: json, minecraft, predicate, minecraft-forge, minecraft-commands

I have followed several tutorials to the letter, and got the "player is_sprinting:true" predicate to work. So I know my fresh new datapack is working.

There are no examples of location predicates anywhere. Videos, wiki, nothing.

I go to a generator and generate the whole predicate, export the whole file, put it in the proper folder, and when I type the path in my tick.mcfunction, Visual Studio Code properly links to it (finally after having to create a new project AND restart my computer to not have the new project auto-fill paths to my old project... for some reason).

It does not detect when a player is within 100 of 0 0 0. It does nothing. Here's what I've tried:

```
{   
    "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",   
    "entity": "this",   
    "predicate": {     
        "type": "minecraft:player",     
        "location": {       
            "position": {         
                "x": 0,         
                "y": 0,         
                "z": 0       
            }     
        },     
        "distance": {       
            "absolute": {         
                "min": 0,         
                "max": 100       
            }     
        }   
    } 
}
```

And...

```
{
    "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",   
    "entity": "this",   
    "predicate": {     
        "type": "minecraft:player",     
        "distance": {       
            "absolute": {         
                "min": 0,         
                "max": 100       
            }     
        }   
    } 
}
```

And...

```
{
    "condition": "minecraft:location_check",   
    "predicate": {     
        "position": {       
            "x": {         
                "min": -100,         
                "max": 100       
            },       
            "y": {
                "min": -100,
                "max": 100
            },       
            "z": {         
                "min": -100,         
                "max": 100       
            }     
        }   
    } 
}
```

All combined with:

```
execute as @a if predicate test:homezone run say hi
```

Or:

```
execute as @a[predicate=test:homezone] run say hi
```

And my player is standing in a new map, at 0, 0, 0 with no other functions running. What's my problem?

Answer (score 0):

when using a predicate as a target selector argument, you need to have the namespaced ID. other than that i'm not really sure. if that dosen't help, try asking on the official minecraft commands discord server, they are good with that stuff. https://discord.gg/QAFXFtZ

for example:

```
@e[predicate=foo:bar]
```

not just

```
@e[predicate=bar]
```

Comment: DAMMNIT! you commented before I corrected it. I know. I had tried like 15 iterations before I started to copy some here. I think I just wrote that from scratch becuase I didn't actually have the first line I wrote, but having it as a target selector was my first choice and I definitely had it linked to the right file because my Visual Studio Code app was suggesting a folder in my old file until I restarted and it refreshed so I know the path was correct on my first go. 

I''ll edit my post now. Thanks for that catch though, good eye. Sorry if I wasted yo time!

Comment: no problem dude, but like i said if that dosen't fix your problem, then ask on that discord server. it's a really good community with lots of people with lots of knowledge

Comment: What's the discord? I'm already a part of the MinecraftCommands Reddit... Discord... is it still a reddit if it's on discord? You referring to that or another one? MinecraftCommands has fast answers mostly but also people misread questions and when you try to clarify someone else asks a question and the chat moves on. I feel weird about everyone moving to discord... No permalinks so when someone figures something out that everyone could use, it gets lost. Anyway when I search "discord stack exchange minecraft" I just get links for people coding ways to integrate discord invites into minecraft.

Comment: it's the discord server of the minecraf commands subreddit. that is a good point about the questions being lost, but there are lots of benefits to asking on ti also. invite: https://discord.gg/QAFXFtZ

Answer (score 0):

locations are weird, I test in superflat void

What you have in your third predicate with the location_check is almost what I have in mine.

```
{
    "condition": "minecraft:location_check",
    "offsetX": -20,
    "offsetY": 0,
    "offsetZ": -20,
    "predicate": {
        "position": {
            "x": {
                "min": 0,
                "max": 2
            },
            "y": 4,
            "z": {
                "min": 0,
                "max": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have running in a command block

```
execute as @p[predicate=test:area] unless predicate test:sneaking run function test:null
```

This detects player at 20 4 20 to 21 4 21 unless sneaking.